# For the find(ID) method, why the system always insists requiring a return type of instructor

Tags: java, arraylist

For the find(ID) method, why the system always insists requiring a return type of instructor, i think i have already declare that the "entry" is of type instructor.

```
// 1. TO DO
/** findID(String) is passed an id and returns the 
 *  Instructor object in the Instructor arraylist having that
 *  id or null if not found
 * @return 
 */

public Instructor findID (String id) {
    for (Instructor entry:instList) {
        if (entry.getId().equals(id) == true) {
            return entry;
        } else return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `instList` collection have a generic type?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you `instList` list is declared as a raw type, ie:

```
List instList = new ArrayList();
```

So, one way to make your code compile, is to declare `instList` with a type:

```
List<Instructor> instList = new ArrayList<Instructor>();
```

If you cannot do it (i.e. you're getting this collection as is from remote source), you can cast it to a required type:

```
for (Instructor entry: (List<Instructor>)instList) {
    ...
}
```

Finally, you can cast retrieved objects instead of casting the whole collection:

```
for (Object entry : instList) {
    Object instructor = (Instructor)entry;
    ...
}
```